# Dynamic result of dynamic input

Tags: javascript, sum

Hello I need to calcul 3 input. the totals of my day ( my input are dynamic made by this button)

```
   $('#calculTempsdiv').append((     '<input id="temps' + counter + '" name="temps[]' + '" type="number" size="10" min="0" max="24" value="0"  class="dynamic" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" onchange="checkField(this.value)"/>'))
```

so how I calculate them and add the result into this ?

```
<td>
    <div id="tempsdimtotal"> 
        <input step="any" type="text" id="tempsdimtotal"  class="temps"  name="tempsdimtotal" size="5"  value="0"  onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"/>
    </div >

</td>
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried.

Comment: //dimanche

$("#calculTemps").on('change','input.temps',function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".temps").each(function() {
        total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $("#result").val(total);
}); something like this

Comment: I tried this too : function checkField(val)
{
 var MaVariable = 0 ;
var monresult = 0 ;

 MaVariable = parseFloat( document.getElementById('temps'+counter).value) ;

monresult = monresult + MaVariable ; 
document.getElementById('tempsdimtotal').value = monresult ;
 alert(monresult);

}

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting code into comments.

Answer (score 0):

here the answer

```
//dimanche calcul
function checkField()
{
    var dynamic = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamic");
     var totaldimanche = document.getElementById("totaldimanche").value;

    var itemCount = dynamic.length;

   var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {

            total = total +  parseFloat(dynamic[i].value);
            total = total + parseFloat( document.getElementById('input1').value  ) ;

    }
    document.getElementById('totaldimanche').value = total;
}
checkField();
```